# mod_rewrite affecting get variables

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP based blog on Apache with a simple mod_rewrite happening:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?story=$1 [L]
```

However, when I look at $_GET['story'] in the PHP script, it gives me "index.php" everytime.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in the DOCUMENT_ROOT? Or do you have higher-up directory RewriteRules? Enable the `RewriteLog` to debug it en detail.

Comment: `$1` is what has been catch by `(.*)`, so it will catch anything from begining to end (due to `^` and `$`). What is the URL you have entered for having the `$_GET['story']` to `index.php` ?

Comment: example.com/blog/index.php?story=12345 = example.com/blog/12345

Answer (score 1):

Apache will run the rules again if there are any changes made during a pass that cause either an internal or external redirect.  You should catch this with a rule for index.php

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

that just uses that address as is.  This is what WordPress does.

Depending on your version of apache you can set the rewrite log level to 8 either with RewriteLogLevel or LogLevel.  On older versions this must be done in the httpd.conf, so you need a local test site.

Don't leave that logging on or your performance will suffer.

Edit:

Here's a quote from the [docs on the rerun](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)  under the L flag:

If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in  sections, it is important to have some understanding of how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.

Comment: I just wonder how many times that happens, and what makes it stop looping

Comment: @WalterTross You can easily create a rewrite infinite loop, I did that a couple of times this afternoon.  Most browsers will let you know by complaining about too many redirects.

Comment: yes, but in this case there is an [L], no [R], and it appears that something like `index.php?story=index.php` or `index.php?story=index.php?story=...` has really been called

Comment: by the way, exactly the docs you mentioned give an alternative solution to the same problem

Comment: @WalterTross I know, there is the END flag.  I'm not sure if that works in older versions of apache, it's not mentioned in my 10 year old apache book. And I haven't tested it.

Comment: @WalterTross That will work too, it prevents a single rule from being applied.  The disadvantage is you would need to apply the condition to all rules, while the WordPress trick short circuits the whole set.  It's always nice to have alternate choices with different advantages.

Comment: @WalterTrosson the no [R], I believe that is implied if you change the target file, creating an internal redirect.  I know you can omit it, I often use [L,R=301] to force a 301 external redirect.